# Unable to setup multiple instances of symmetricDS on a vm

Tags: replication, symmetricds

Please I have two instances of symmetricds running on my vm using the commands:

```
bin/sym --port 9000
bin/sym --port 4000
```

but I want to be able to run both instances through the linux service. I have tried installing the service using 'bin/sym_service install' in the respective directories. But it's not working and when I try to start the server I get an error stating that the port is in use.

How can I set up the linux service to use different ports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run multiple services of SymmetricDS on the same machine, you will need to:

- Set unique port numbers for http, https, and jmx in conf/symmetric-server.properties.
- Set unique service name for wrapper.name in conf/sym_service.conf

Then you can run "bin/sym_service install" to install the init script.  On a side note, consider if it makes sense to run multiple nodes inside the same instance by placing multiple engine.properties files in the "engines" directory.

Answer (score 1):

Find out which program is listening to the used port and kill it with `kill -9 PROCESS_NUMBER`. Then try again.

To run on a different port execute `bin/sym --port 3000` server as stated in symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_sym_launcher

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is the default port used by symmetricDS is 31415. So there's a clash as the two instances are trying to utilize the same port. so if i can specify the ports to be used by the different instances it will work, but i don't know how to do that

Comment: Two instances are not needed. You can register more than one symmetricDs engine under the same instance by providing several `symmetric-ds-*.properties` files

Comment: yeah i was able to get ```bin/sym --port 3000``` to work but i could not figure out how to set the ports when using the linux service